# Firefox inspector - CSS rules suggestions/hints

Tags: css, firefox

I have a problem with the inspector in Firefox browser. After some time of use, in the "rules" tab, system don't want to show me CSS syntax suggestions. After switching the inspector off and on, everything returns back to normal, but ... again ... after a few moments, the system stops showing me syntax hints.

[image: firefox inspector rules tab]

```
           with syntax hints                           without syntax hints
                                                    after a couple of minutes
```

Is there any FIX for this? I'm using newest "FireFox Developer Edition" (same thing on normal "Firefox").

**UPDATE:**
I discovered that inspector starts to work improperly when I restart a page which I have been "inspecting".

Comment: Tried running FF with the addons disabled?

Comment: @j08691 Nope, it's not that. I've disabled all addons and the problem still appears :(.

Comment: I left my DevTools open on this page for 24-hours and the hints still work. When you trigger this, does anything show up in the global console? (Menu -> Developer -> Browser Console)

Comment: @Callahad Well... maybe it's breaking only while using. Where is "Developer" menu item?

Comment: @Callahad I discovered that inspector starts to work improperly when I restart a page which I have been "inspecting".

Comment: I would surely want to know who have downvoted me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Are you using Firefox Developer Edition 41.0a2? It appears to have possibly been a bug that is being corrected.**

I can confirm this happens in Firefox 40.0.2.
[image]

I also saw this in Firefox Developer Edition 41.0a2.

**I updated Firefox Developer Edition to 42.0a2 and am no longer able to recreate this phenomenon.**

Comment: Yeah, I saw it works now after latest update :). They should add my nick to contributors section that I found that bug :P!

Comment: In spite of this being a good answer I think actually, it does not contain enough information yet. But since nobody created a more comprehensive one, I just give you the bounty...

Comment: For example, the information whether an entry on bugzilla exists, a quickfix and the information when this fixed version is likely to be released are missing.

Comment: @Matmarbon I posted a question on Mozilla forum. They didn't respond about that problem. So... can't get any more informations about that bug nor fix :/.

Comment: @Matmarbon - I did look  for bugs and [this particular one does not appear to be reported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=firefox+developer+tools+autocomplete). Perhaps the OP would like to report it. I am assuming since it seems to be fixed in the latest developer edition that it may be related to one of the many tool-tip popup bugs.

Answer (score -2):

Install firebug plugin for firefox. Ita a very good debugger tool. After installing enable it and right click on page and do "inspect element with firebug"

Comment: Yeah, I know about that plugin existance. But still... I need a native Firefox inspector.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question